# Fix the "deivatives" tag

Tags: bug, status-completed

I noticed there is a tag called *deivatives* which should really be *derivatives*. Could a moderator please fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for noticing and bringing it to our attention. I've merged the old tag into the new one.